# Remove Structure from Copy

Tags: tfs-2015, minimatch

I have a Task on my TFS build to Copy files to the staging folder:

[image: Copy Files Task]

Currently, this builds the staging folder with all the subfolder structure, e.g. `\MyProject\bin\release\`

Is there a way to set this so that it dumps to just `\MyProject\`, without the `bin\release` portions?

Comment: Do you mean that you just want to copy the contents you specified **\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\** to \MyProject folder, or just ignore the bin\release contents?

Comment: @Andy-MSFT The latter. I want the contents of that folder, I just don't want the structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change the output path :

- Configure the build configuration output path, eg set **".\"**  as
  out path (In solution right click the project > properties > Build > Output > Output path).
- Specify the output path in **MSBuild Arguments** such as
  `/p:OutputPath=$(Build.BinariesDirectory)` then copy from `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)` directly. Reference screenshot below.

Besides, you can also try to copy the contents to stage folder first. then add another **Copy Files** step to copy the `\MyProject\bin\release\**` to `\MyProject`

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Obsidian Phoenix Have you resolved the issue by above workaround? any update?